# Alternative to storing an image path

Tags: javascript, html

I need to dynamically generate a catalogue of items on my page. Each item consists of description data that is stored in a JSON object. Each item needs to have an image associated with it. The user fills out a form for the description data and selects an image from their computer "to upload". The javascript right now is replacing a placeholder image in the page with an image the user selects from their system. I want to be able to store the path of the image or the image itself in the JSON object. Can this be done?  I have read that you cannot store the absolute file path for security reasons. I cannot use a server, or jQuery, as this is "simulated" behavior for an assignment.

EDIT: I updated the code to follow the mozilla developer tutorial suggested by Varinder but it does not work. Did I implement this incorrectly?

my html code:

```
<div class="uploadImgContainer">
    <img src="images/upload_wText.png" id="uploadImgCont" alt="Image"/>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
var petImg; // global variable to store petImg 
function uploadPetImg(imagePath){
    document.getElementById('uploadImgCont').src=imagePath; 
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('uploadImageBtn').addEventListener('change',function(event){
var imagePath=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
uploadPetImg(imagePath);

/* to store imagePath of image */
var preview = document.querySelector('uploadImageBtn');
var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
var fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.addEventListener("load", function(){
    preview.src = fReader.result;
}, false);
if(file){
    petImg = fReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
});
}
```

When I inspect the page in Chrome, the field in the JSON object doesn't show at all. There should be a last field called petImg. The output is: 
{"petName":"dash","username":"bry","petType":"cat","petBreed":"russian blue","petAge":"8","petGender":"male","petLocation":"sd","records":"yes"}

Any alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could convert image into a base64 data url (downside being the string could be huge for bigger files) more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: Varinder, I saw this link already, but I didn't understand how to store the converted file into a JSON object. Would you just set a field in the JSON object to the filefeader's evaluation?  I have a field called petImg in the JSON object. Would I do something like petImg = reader.readAsDataURL(file); ?

Comment: Yup, and if you're intending to send JSON over the wire then you'll have to ```JSON.stringify()``` something like ```JSON.stringify({ petImg: reader.readAsDataURL(file) });```

Comment: There are no "JSON objects". That concept does not exist, it's nonsense, get it out of your head. There are either objects, or there is JSON. JSON *always* is a string, it never is an "object".